# texture paint texture missing texture paint paint

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm not necessarily good at blender and especially not textures or materials, the stems of my problem. I was on my merry way, texturing a model I had recently made, but as I often do, I had a bad idea.
I changed from Principled BSDF to Toon BSDF and tweaked a few settings until I started messing with an option I should not have messed with. Suddenly, my texture vanished. Startled, I undid whatever it was I did to find my texture, without my texture paint progress; nothing but a blank canvas. After about an hour and a half of desperately looking for someone with the same problem as me, but to no avail. 'twas when I ran to here in search of a wiser one to bring upon me the answer.

I made a thing in texture paint and after screwing around in the material settings it was gone.
The image is still there and so is the preview but the paint has gone the way of the dodo.

[image]

Comment: It happens when you don't save the image after painting. You need to always save the image when you paint, either by packing it or by saving it externally. See this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/233608/115533

Comment: Thank you, it's unfortunate that the image is gone for good but i'm glad now I know. Thanks.